# Complicated integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to do this complicated integral:[image]

and draw a plot about A(F(R)):

[image]

where gamma function is:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
S[k_,R_] :=k^3 (Log[1+2.34k]/(2.34k))^2 (1+3.89k+(16.1k)^2+(5.46k)^3+(6.71k)^4)^-0.5 (3Sin[k*R]/(k*R)^3-3Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^2)^2; F[r_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[S[k,r],{k,0,Infinity}];LogLogPlot[(R/((2Pi)^0.5 F[R]^(3/2))) Exp[-1/(2F[R])]+(1/((2(2Pi)^0.5)F[R]^(3/2))) Gamma[1/(2F[R]),0],{R, 1/10,0.5}]
```

I can't get the right plot, in which A(F) should be a monotonically decreasing function,but what I get is a increasing one with the code above. Could you please help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post un-searchable images of equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.  Also, never use upper-case letters for variables as they conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal naming conventions.

Comment: Replace two `F(R)` with `F[R]`. Don't know if there are other errors in the code because your desktop published version doesn't seem to exactly match your code version. It takes a very long time to run. Next, things that worry me. `NIntegrate` out to Infinity. I changed infinity to 1000 and it was still slow, changed to 100 and now I quickly get a plot. I would change powers of 0.5 and -0.5 into `Sqrt` See if these fix your problem and you get a good plot. Then decide if you want to wait for Infinity.

Comment: Is this a "complex integral" or a "complicated integral"?

Answer (score 2):

Change definition `S[k,R}`

```
    S[k_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ] := 
  k^3 (Log[1 + 2.34 k]/(2.34 k))^2 (1 + 
      3.89 k + (16.1 k)^2 + (5.46 k)^3 + (6.71 k)^4)^-0.5 (3 Sin[
         k*R]/(k*R)^3 - 3 Cos[k*R]/(k*R)^2)^2;
```

Now this function is only evaluated if the arguments are numeric.

With your definition

```
F[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[S[k, r], {k, 0, Infinity}];
```

it's possible to evaluate pointwise

```
data = Table[{R, (R/((2 Pi)^0.5 F[R]^(3/2))) Exp[-1/(2 F[R])] + (1/((2 (2Pi)^0.5) F[R]^(3/2))) Gamma[1/(2 F[R]),0]}, {R, Range[.1, .5, .01]}];
data // Log // ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"Log[R]", "Log[A[F]]"}] &
```

[image]

`LogLogPlot`needs some time to evaluate

```
LogLogPlot[(R/((2 Pi)^0.5 F[R]^(3/2))) Exp[-1/(2 F[R])] + (1/((2 (2Pi)^0.5) F[R]^(3/2))) Gamma[1/(2 F[R]),0], {R, 1/10, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!